# Visual Studio Community Mac Change Line Number Bar Color

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to tweak my IDE settings for VS2017 Community Mac. I have download a theme and everything looks good except for the fact that the line numbers & column they are in are white (see below). Is there a way to change this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify what type of theme you are using (.json, .vssettings, textmate(?)), so add/update your theme with following and adjust the colors to your preference:

#### .vssettings:

```
<Item Name="Line Number" Foreground="0x00494E3F" Background="0x00343129" BoldFont="No"/>
```

#### `.json`:

```
{"name": "Line Numbers", "fore":"#BDBDBD", "back":"#2A2A25" },
```

#### textmate (not really sure this is even supported any more):

```
<Style name="linenumber" color="#AAAAAA" bgColor="#FDFDFD" />
```

Comment: Ahh i see.. I wasn't aware there were multiple types. The .vssettings should do it thanks!

Comment: @Broncos423 No problem ;-)